# Error while loading List to DropDownList in flutter

Tags: flutter

1. I have an Api response like

`[{"Food_name":"value1"},{"Food_name":"value2"},{"Food_name":"value3"},{"Food_name":"value4"},{"Food_name":"value5"}]`

I got the reponse in a List Food_Name, but when try to show this list in dropdown showing an error as type List is not a subtype of List>, may be I am using it wrong way. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share the code you tried for displaying dropdown

Comment: child: DropdownButton(
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    items: Food_NameValue,
                                    value: field.value,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      field.didChange(value);
                                    },
                                  ),

Answer (score 1):

List cannot be directly supplied to items.

Items accept

```
List<DropdownMenuItem<T>> items
```

What you have is

```
List<Map<String,String>>
```

```
var jsonList = [
    {"Food_name": "value1"},
    {"Food_name": "value2"},
    {"Food_name": "value3"},
    {"Food_name": "value4"},
    {"Food_name": "value5"}
  ];

......
......



child: DropdownButton(
            onChanged: (value){

            },
            items: jsonList.map((Map<String, String> value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value["Food_name"],
                child: Text(value["Food_name"]),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: This is working now, the above error was because I had put the List variable inside setstate()

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use : PopupMenuButton

```
Widget _typeTeachPopup() => PopupMenuButton<Food>(
    onSelected: _selectFood,
    child: ListTile(
      title: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0, right: 0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return _listFoods.map((Food choice) {
        return PopupMenuItem<TypeTeach>(
          value: choice,
          child: Text(choice.food_name),
        );
      }).toList();
    },
  );
```

The result is as follows :

[image]

Comment: I cannot use popup, as it is a different component. I need dropdown button